# Apache httpclient HTTPGET decoding

Tags: java, api, utf-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm consuming an API which encodes german umlauts in UTF-8. My application needs to decode and encode these characters. Encoding is not a problem an works totally fine. To achieve that I set a charset while creating a new `StringEntity` and adding that to the request like this:

```
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(getUrl);
    if(useProxy) {
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setProxy(proxy)
                .build();
        request.setConfig(config);
    }
    request.addHeader("APIKey", apiKey);
    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    request.setEntity(new 
    StringEntity(JsonUtils.getJsonFromObject(nachricht), "UTF-8"));
```

All the special characters like umlauts are sent and stored correctly in the backend.
However when I want to retrieve this data it leads to some errors which look like this:
[image]

Small characters work, but capital letters don't. It seems like the response or HTTPGET-request is ISO_8859_1-encoded. How can I set the charset of a HTTPGET to UTF-8? I already tried setting the requestheader like this:

```
request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

And decoding the content of the response like this:

```
byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity).getBytes();
String responseString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

But since the charset of the response seems to be wrong, decoding with UTF-8 leads to an error..

Comment: It more seems there is a wrong to-lower-case conversion, were it not for the initial 'T.' First dump the int values of the chars of the java Strings and check them. Maybe the "capitals" are smallcaps letters in a high Unicode range.

Comment: Just umlauts are converted wrong, the letters which are broken on my screenshot are Ö, Ä and Ü while ö, ä and ü work properly..

Comment: I bet `é` and `÷` (\u00F7) work too, but `É` not. It must be the java part. Maybe  there is a **validation** somewhere with a regex listing `äöüß` but not `ÄÖÜ`. Amd somehow - as UTF-8 can do all Unicode -, there must have happened a conversion/replacement to receive the ?-placeholder

Comment: Other possibility, quite remote: some conversion to Latin-1, plus that the capitals were not taken from a German keyboard and were wrongly picked from the Character Map application: `ȀŐŰ`. In every case better dump the values in java; that ensures that they were read correctly from the database (MySQL is famous for its additional useUnicode URL). `s = s.replaceAll("\\p{ASCII}", mr -> mr.group() + Arrays.toString(mr.group().codePoints().toArray()))`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by passing a param "UTF-8" to responseEntity:

```
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, "UTF-8");
```